# How to move a file to a different folder based on user input in powershell

Tags: powershell

HI Everyone I am trying to write a script for my powershell practice to move a file from one folder to another based on user input. The script works fine but only if the file exists in the folder same as the script. Can someone please help me what i am doing wrong or try to help with logic

```
$destination = 'P:\Powershell practice\Movefolder'
$ListFile = "P:\Powershell practice\" 
get-childitem $ListFile
$Filename = Read-host -prompt "Please Enter File to be moved"
$FileExists =  test-path $Filename

If ($FileExists -eq $True) {
move-item $Filename $destination
Write-Host "File is moved to $destination "
}
else
{write-host "No File Found"}
```

Comment: at first i list all the content of the powershell practice folder so that user can type the exact name of the file to be moved. Problem is its only looking for the file where i am running the script, it should look under $listfile for the filename which user had input and then move it across

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine the full file path otherwise the test-path check whether the file exists at the current location. You can use the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet to join the pass:

```
$FilePath = Join-Path $ListFile $FileName
$FileExists =  test-path $FilePath 

If ($FileExists -eq $True) {
move-item $FilePath $destination
...
```

**Offtopic:**
You could also use a Grid-View where the user can select multiple files and press the ok button at the bottom to copy the files ;-):

```
$destination = 'P:\Powershell practice\Movefolder'
$ListFile = 'P:\Powershell practice\' 

$filesToMove = get-childitem $ListFile | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple
$filesToMove | % { move-item $_.FullName $destination}
```

Comment: check my update on that answer. Maybe it fits your needs as well.

Comment: that is even nicer. I liked this as well, will play a bit more with these to see which fits my need

Answer (score 0):

Incase if someone needs. Below is the correct working script for this

```
$destination = 'P:\Powershell practice\Movefolder'
$ListFile = 'P:\Powershell practice\' 
get-childitem $ListFile
$Filename = Read-host -prompt "Please Enter File to be moved"
$FilePath = Join-Path $ListFile $FileName
$FileExists =  test-path $FilePath 

If ($FileExists -eq $True) {
move-item $FilePath $destination
Write-Host "File is moved to $destination "
}
else
{write-host "No File Found"}
```